# Getting java.lang.AssertionError when generating birt report from my application when server is started in debug mode

Tags: birt

When generating my Birt report in debug mode I am getting below error as
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connection.java:189)

but it works fine when generated in normal mode.

Comment: In Java, the assert statement is only active in debug mode. Without debug mode, the assert statement is just not evaluated. Personally, I consider this a language design error.

Comment: thanks for your comment, if it is a language design error , there may be a way to disable assert evaluation even in debug mode also. Is there any such possibility?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Anyway you should post more details of the error message.